# Trouble initializing a struct array

Tags: arduino-uno, array, struct

The goal for this is to create a struct that includes a name, ID, fileName, and a boolean, then create an array of that structs.
Here's what I came up with:

```
struct Amiibo
{
  char *aName{};
  char *ID{};
  char *AudioFileName{};
  bool alreadyPlayed{false};
};  

Amiibo amii[20] = {

      {"Mario","A5005B00","MARIO",false},                     //0
      {"Meta Knight","A5 00 02 00","MK"},                     //1
      {"Inkling", "A5 00 05 00","INK"},                       //2
      {"Donkey Kong","A5 00 01 00","DK"},                     //3
      {"Lucas","A5 00 0A 00","LUCAS"},                        //4
      {"Duck Hunt", "A5 00 08 00","DUCKH"},                   //5
      {"Ocarina of Time Link","A5 00 01 00","OOTL"},          //6
      {"Breath of The Wild Link","random","BOTWL"},           //7
      {"8-bit Link","random","8BITL"},                        //8
      {"Toon Link","random","TOONL"},                         //9      
      {"Mr. Game and Watch","random","GANDW"},                //10
      {"Falco","random","FALCO"},                             //11
      {"King Dedede","random","DEDEDE"},                      //12
      {"Mewtwo","random","MEWTWO"},                           //13
      {"Captain Falcon","random","CAPF"},                     //14
      {"ROB","random","ROB"},                                 //15
      {"PAC-MAN","random","PACMAN"},                          //16
      {"Cloud","random","CLOUD"},                             //17
      {"Ness","random","NESS"},                               //18
      {"Ryu","random","RYU"}                                  //19

};
```

This gives me the following error:

> error: could not convert '{"Mario", "A5005B00", "MARIO", false}' from '' to 'Amiibo'

And the same error for all the other elements of the array.
I tried changing amii[20] to a pointer using *amii[20]. That got me this error:

> braces around scalar intializer for type "Amiibo"

I'm not sure what to make of that, since I'm fairly certain this isn't scalar type.

I'd really just like to make a struct array so I can cycle through these at random using a random seed. It shouldn't be that difficult, yet I'm running up against a wall. I'd appreciate any advice you all have to give. Thanks.

Comment: If you use default values, you can't use this type of initialization, you have to have proper constructor(s) to get it working. However it'll tricky with that C-strings

Comment: Would you mind giving an example of a proper constructor?

Comment: `struct Amiibo {` ... `Amiibo(const char* name, const char* id, const char * audio) : aName{ name }, ID{ id }, AudioFileName{ audio } { ; }` and another one with 4 parameters... (btw you have to change internal types to `const char *` too, otherwise it'll yell about discarding qualifier)

Comment: Simply omit the default values?!

Answer (score 1):

If you use default values in struct declaration, you have to define also constructors for setting specific elements:

```
struct Amiibo
{
  const char *aName{};
  const char *ID{};
  const char *AudioFileName{};
  bool alreadyPlayed{false};

  Amiibo() = default;  // default implementation for default constructor
  
  Amiibo(const char* name, const char* id, const char * audio)  // constructor with three c strings as parameters
  : aName{ name }
  , ID{ id }
  , AudioFileName{ audio }
  { ; }
};  

Amiibo amii[] = {
      {"Mario","A5005B00","MARIO"},                           //0
      {"Meta Knight","A5 00 02 00","MK"},                     //1
      {"Inkling", "A5 00 05 00","INK"},                       //2
      {"Donkey Kong","A5 00 01 00","DK"},                     //3
      {"Lucas","A5 00 0A 00","LUCAS"},                        //4
      {"Duck Hunt", "A5 00 08 00","DUCKH"},                   //5
      {"Ocarina of Time Link","A5 00 01 00","OOTL"},          //6
      {"Breath of The Wild Link","random","BOTWL"},           //7
      {"8-bit Link","random","8BITL"},                        //8
      {"Toon Link","random","TOONL"},                         //9      
      {"Mr. Game and Watch","random","GANDW"},                //10
      {"Falco","random","FALCO"},                             //11
      {"King Dedede","random","DEDEDE"},                      //12
      {"Mewtwo","random","MEWTWO"},                           //13
      {"Captain Falcon","random","CAPF"},                     //14
      {"ROB","random","ROB"},                                 //15
      {"PAC-MAN","random","PACMAN"},                          //16
      {"Cloud","random","CLOUD"},                             //17
      {"Ness","random","NESS"},                               //18
      {"Ryu","random","RYU"}                                  //19
};
```

Btw on the older AVRs all those strings will resides also in memory

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I may end up just using a switch or something to avoid memory issues.